# Entry animation runs before google-youtube element is loaded

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0, paper-elements

*Polymer 1.0*

I have a custom element where the entry animation starts before the element is completely loaded. This causes the `<paper-button>` to have the animation before `<google-youtube>` is loaded, which looks funny.

I think the `'iron-overlay-opened'` is fired before all the elements are loaded...in this case the `<paper-button>` is loaded but the `<google-youtube>` is not.

How can I make it to where the custom element loads completely first so the `entry` animation is applied correctly?

*This is using `paper-dialog-behavior` element*

```
<dom-module id="video-player">
  <style>
     :host {
      @apply(--layout-fit);
     }
  </style>


  <template>
    <template is="dom-if" if="{{foo.bar}}">
      <div class="layout vertical fit">
        <google-youtube style="height: 100%"
          video-id="YMWd7QnXY8E"
          rel="1"
          start="1"
          playsinline="0"
          controls="2"
          showinfo="0"
          width="100%"
          height="100%"
          autoplay="1">
        </google-youtube>
      </div>
      <paper-button dialog-dismiss style="color: white; margin-top: 0px">
        <paper-icon-button icon="arrow-back"></paper-icon-button>
      </paper-button>
    </template>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "video-player",
      behaviors: [ 
        Polymer.PaperDialogBehavior,
        Polymer.NeonAnimationRunnerBehavior
                 ],
      properties: {
        foo: Object,
        entryAnimation: {
          value: 'scale-up-animation'
        },
        exitAnimation: {
          value: 'fade-out-animation'
        }
      },
      listeners: { 'iron-overlay-opened': 'enableElement',
                   'iron-overlay-closed': 'stopPlayer'
      },
      startPlayer: function() {
        youtubePlayer = this.$$('google-youtube');
        if (youtubePlayer.playbackstarted) {
         youtubePlayer.play();
        }
      },
      enableElement: function(e) {
        this.foo = { bar: true};
        this.playAnimation('entry');
        setTimeout(this.startPlayer.bind(this), 300);
      },
      stopPlayer: function(e) {
        this.playAnimation('exit');
        youtubePlayer = this.$$('google-youtube');
        youtubePlayer.pause();
        youtubePlayer.seekTo(1);
      },
      ready: function() {
        console.log("sssssssssssssssssSS");
       }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: it might be an issue with the scale-up-animation drawing things after it opens and scaled up. Have you tried a diferent animation like (slide-from-left-animation) to see if does the same

Comment: No, issue is not with animation itself.

Comment: it's hard to envision the issue. you should do a basic demo on http://codepen.io/